# How to georeference image with GCP in aux.xml using Affine transformation

Tags: qgis, gdal, georeferencing, ground-control

I'm trying to automate georeference of big amount of non/georeferenced image file stored in TIF format to work with them in QGIS 3.16.4-Hannover.
These TIF files are 8 bits (B/N) and I only have aux.xml sidecar file containing a list of GCP.

This is an example of a PAM Dataset *.aux.xml file:

```
<PAMDataset>    
   <SRS dataAxisToSRSAxisMapping="1,2">PROJCS["...",GEOGCS["...,"AUTHORITY["EPSG","23031"]]]</SRS>    
   <PAMRasterBand band="1">    
      <Metadata>          
         <MDI key="STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE">YES</MDI>          
         <MDI key="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM">250</MDI>          
         <MDI key="STATISTICS_MEAN">105.39136338541</MDI>          
         <MDI key="STATISTICS_MINIMUM">0</MDI>          
         <MDI key="STATISTICS_STDDEV">62.095857421551</MDI>          
         <MDI key="STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT">100</MDI>        
      </Metadata>      
   </PAMRasterBand>      
   <GCPList>
      <GCP Id="" Pixel="10627.14063" Line="2047.42188" X="303207.84625" Y="4709035.90307" />        
      <GCP Id="" Pixel="12700.51563" Line="13847.60938" X="303973.58269" Y="4705214.27235" />        
      <GCP Id="" Pixel="14836.50000" Line="9597.48438" X="304752.03808" Y="4706639.88411" />    
      ... (more than 50 GCP points) ...
      <GCP Id="" Pixel="9628.54688" Line="6340.40625" X="302924.73400" Y="4707741.75435" />      
   </GCPList>    
</PAMDataset>
```

There are several possible transformation methods in GDAL [Ref1, pag 20]: TPS, Affine, 2nd and 3rd order polynomials. By default, polynomial order 1 will be selected if there are less than 6 points, otherwise polynomial order 2.

[Ref1] https://download.osgeo.org/gdal/workshop/foss4ge2015/workshop_gdal.pdf (Pg 20)

I have to maintain my list of GCP points but I need to use an affine transformation.
I have seen in some ESRI aux.xml file `<PolynomialOrder>` tag, but QGIS doesn't recognize the `<PolynomialOrder>1</PolynomialOrder>` instruction.

Is there any TAG in aux.xml file to set the transformation method to overpass GDAL default behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gdalwarp https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html with `-order 1` but instead of writing a new TIFF use VRT https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html as outputformat.

Command:

```
gdalwarp -of VRT -order 1 image.tif image.vrt
```

Open the image.vrt file with QGIS and it will apply the first order polynomial on-the-fly.

`PolynomialOrder` appears only in the ESRI variant of aux.xml. GDAL does support also that but I do not know if it applies the PolynomialOrder instruction automatically. Maybe you can write ESRI style aux.xml by using https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gcore/pam.py#L459 as a template and test.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, it works perfect! Regarding the VRT format, do the values of <GeoTransform> correspond to those of the TFW of the image? ...even if the image is rotated?

Comment: Yes, the GDAL GeoTransform defines the affine transformation https://gdal.org/user/raster_data_model.html#affine-geotransform in the same way than TFW.